# Explain python Singleton class

Tags: python, singleton

```
class Singleton:

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

singleton_obj1 = Singleton()
singleton_obj2 = Singleton()

print(singleton_obj1)
print(singleton_obj2)
```

**output**

```
<__main__.Singleton object at 0x10dbc0f60>
<__main__.Singleton object at 0x10dbc0f60>
```

Can someone explain what exactly happening at this line `cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)`. Which lines of code helped to make this class `Singleton`?

Comment: That's a pretty bad singleton implementation, by the way. It'll call `__init__` every time you call `Singleton()`, so your singleton will keep getting its attributes reset. (If you have an `__init__` method)

Comment: @Aran-Fey can you provide some links to better implementations

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/1222951

Comment: `__new__` is not the same as `__init__`. In fact, for this implementation `__new__` is the correct magic, because a Singleton does not need to be initialized if one instance already exists.  Here's a blog that explains the difference: http://howto.lintel.in/python-__new__-magic-method-explained/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, to go over this in painful detail:

`class Singleton:` implicitly inherits from `Object` because in python *everything* is an Object.

`instance = None` is only read at module load time, and sets the class level variable `instance` to be `None` *one time* but it can be over written by individual instances of the class `Singleton`.

```
def __new__(cls):
    if cls.instance is None:
        cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)
    return cls.instance
```

(First off,  I think that it's weird that they put "cls" in there, I know why they did it, because it's referring to the class *overall* and not a specific instance of that class.  But, it can be confusing so someone who doesn't know what they're looking at.  Anyway...)

`__new__` is a magic function that is called before `__init__`, that is roughly analogous to allocating the space for the new instance of the class.  Here, `cls.instance` was set to `None` on module load, and so every time a new `Singleton` is being created this test is done.  Since `cls.instance` is set the first time a `Singleton` is created, the `super().__new__(cls)` is also *only called once*.  The super class of `Singleton` is `Object`.  So the behavior of the `super().__new__(cls)` is exactly what you'd expect it to be for any other class you create.
If, you are creating a second(, or third/fourth/fifth...) instance of `Singleton` then this `super().__new__(cls)` will not be called.  Instead the class level variable `instance` is returned, meaning that *no new instances of `Singleton` can be created*.

When you print the instances of `Singleton` then you can see the memory address of `0x10dbc0f60` is the same for both "instances" because `cls.instance` is returned at `__new__` time, which you can think of as memory allocation time, before `__init__` is called.

This is a good way to do a Singleton pattern because in order to create a singleton class, now, all you have to do is inherit from `Singleton` and the heavy lifting is already done.  You go ahead and use `__init__` like you normally would, and don't worry about it.  Every time you go to create a "new" instance of that class, you'll get the same instance back.  Totally behind the scenes.

This is pretty advanced stuff, but look how simple it is.  python is the best!

Comment: Thank you !! very well explained.

Answer (score 9):

The constructor says,

```
If there is no instance recorded, 
   create an instance and record it
return the recorded instance
```

This is a standard singleton design pattern, for most languages, to ensure that only one instance of the class is ever created.

Comment: why singleton_obj1 and singleton_obj2 did not get separate copies of `instance`?

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri Because `instance` is a class variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: When `Singleton()` is called for the second time, `instance` is not `None`, so the `if` does not go ahead and make a new instance. The previous instance is returned.

Comment: Because a Singleton should, by definition always return the same instance. For example, a factory class, should only be constructed once, but used in many places, so it should be made a Singleton.